# iPhone : How to empty the call stack when exits from a view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my ViewController I have scheduled some method calls(will be called after some time), in some cases I jump to another viewController before these method schedules gets completed. How can I cancel all method calls or empty the call stack before starting another ViewController ?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you schedule the calls?

Comment: I am making some network call, after completion of which method will be called.

Comment: If you keep references to the requests you make, then you can cancel them before showing a new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSTimer to schedule method call then add in -(void)viewwilldisappear
Timer invalidate code so that before going to next view controller.

Comment: Please tell me you have schedule the methods call